# File.copy over network

Tags: c#, networking, copy

I'm trying to copy files from a local pc to a server with file.copy. but whitou succes.
there are no error but it doesn't show up on the server. my Permissons are alright thow.

here is what i do.

```
    public static void UploadFiles(string path, string[] files, 
                         string[] uploadPlace, ObserverDelegate observerDelegete)
    {
        try
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count(); i++)
            {
                observerDelegete(files[i]);
                File.Copy(files[i], uploadPlace[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uoe) { }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) { }
        catch (Exception e) { }        
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure there are really no errors? You are pretty much ignoring errors with that `catch (...)` statements.

Comment: you should start by removing all the catch blocks. then debug again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no error because you're catching and swallowing *all* of the possible exceptions...

```
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uoe) { }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) { }
    catch (Exception e) { }
```

which effectively masks the errors from you as a programmer. Take those statements out, recompile the code, and see what exceptions get thrown.

It's likely a permissions or network connectivity issue. Windows is nice enough to let you know for sure.

Comment: i was still in debug mode, i followed every step. there are no error, but the: Directory.CreateDirectory(path); doesn't work either

Comment: @Jorne: Debug mode has nothing to do with this. Those exceptions will still be caught and swallowed in "Debug" mode. What are the arguments you're passing into the function? Do you have a network drive mapped? Are you specifying a UNC path?

Comment: Yes that was it! i dit \servername istat of \\servername
stupid mistake, my bad. thamks!